# How to insert image in odoo 12 docker qweb report

Tags: docker, odoo, odoo-12, qweb

I would like to insert an image from mymodule folder but the image doesn't display. I'm using docker for this odoo.

This is my code:
`<img src="/my_module/static/img/img.png" width="100%" height="100%"/>`

The result is here below:
[image]

I found a similar case: https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/32674 but in my case, this solution is not working

Could anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. Just change value on key in system parameter `web.base.url` to `http://127.0.0.1:8069`. I think this only work with docker installation.